# Choosing specific symbols to print in a random string

Tags: python, symbols

I am trying to print a random string which contains upper and lowercase letters, digits and symbols. This is my code:

```
genpassword = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters
                                     + string.digits
                                     + string.punctuation)
                       for n in range(12)])
```

So far it works. However, I want the program to only print specific symbols, which are the following:

```
symbols = ["!","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","-","_","=","+"]
```

The **string.punctuation** prints all these symbols but some others.

***So how do I get my program to generate a string which contains only symbols from the list above?***

Comment: `random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + ''.join(symbols))`

Comment: @PM2Ring I think, since they're making a password then the `random` module may not be a secure option, compared to say the new Py3.6 `secrets` module

Comment: @Chris_Rands Good point. OTOH, we don't know whether this is a "toy" program, or whether the OP intends to use it to generate real passwords. FWIW, I wouldn't bother with the symbols, since they give little benefit in improving the security, but I guess many sites insist that passwords have some non-alphanumeric symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the characters you want into a string, and then use that instead of `string.punctuation`:

```
symbols = "!$%^&*()-_=+"
genpassword = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + symbols ) for n in range(12)])
```

This is actually how your code already works, for example `string.ascii_letters` is just a string as well, see in Python interpreter (a good way to experiment):

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```